# How to fix critical iteration problem in my kivmd app? and how can I print the in the riskeval screen from my location function?

Tags: python, kivymd

Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame
. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute. Remaining even
ts:
<ClockEvent (-1.0) callback=<bound method AnchorLayout.do_layout of <kivymd.uix.
button.MDRaisedButton object at 0x15A28990>>>
This is what I get when I try to run.

python

```
    import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from kivy.factory import Factory
import json
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SignUp(Screen):
    pass

class SignUptwo(Screen):
    pass

class RiskEval(Screen):
    def on_enter(self,*args):
        url='https://ipinfo.io/json'
        res=urlopen(url)
        data=json.load(res)
        region=data["region"]
        print(region)
        if region=='Ajman':
            case_rate=100;
            vaccination_rate=90;
            print(vaccination_rate)
            print(case_rate)
            print(self.manager.get_screen("riskeval").ids.evaluation.text)
        if region=='Sharjah':
            case_rate=200;
            vaccination_rate=80;
            print(vaccination_rate)
            print(case_rate)
        if region=='Dubai':
            case_rate=500;
            vaccination_rate=90;
            print(vaccination_rate)
            print(case_rate)
        if region=='Abu Dhabi':
            case_rate=480;
            vaccination_rate=70;
            print(vaccination_rate)
            print(case_rate)
        if region=='Ras Al Khaimah':
            case_rate=150;
            vaccination_rate=40;
            print(vaccination_rate)
            print(case_rate)
        if region=='Umm Al Quwain':
            case_rate=90;
            vaccination_rate=35;
            print(vaccination_rate)
            print(case_rate)
        if region=='Fujairah':
            case_rate=50;
            vaccination_rate=20;
            print(vaccination_rate)
            print(case_rate)
        
    
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass 




class Thirdapp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("layout.kv")

    
        '''def caserate(self, case):
        self.ids.rate.text = ""
        self.ids.rate.text = f'{case}' '''

    def check(self, checkbox, active):
        if active:
            print("Vaccinated")
    def check1(self, checkbox, active):
        if active:
            print("UnVaccinated")
    def check2(self, checkbox, active):
        if active:
            print("Male")
    def check3(self, checkbox, active):
        if active:
            print("Female")
if __name__== "__main__":
    Thirdapp().run()
```

kivyfile

```
    WindowManager:
    
    SignUp:
    LoginScreen:
    RiskEval:
        id: riskevaluation
    SignUptwo:


<SignUp>:
    name: "signup"

    
    MDFloatLayout:

        MDCard:
            size_hint: 0.75, 0.9
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        MDLabel:
            text: "Sign-Up"
            bold: True
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
            font_style: "H4"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "First Name"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .64}
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
            multiline: False
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Last Name"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .56}
            helper_text: "*Required"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            multiline: False
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Email Address"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .48}
            helper_text: "*Required"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            icon_left: "email"
            email: True
            multiline: False
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Phone number"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .40}
            helper_text: "*Required"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            icon_left: "phone"
            multiline: False
            max_text_length: 10
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Password"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .32}
            helper_text: "*Required"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            password: True
            icon_left: 'key-variant'
            icon_right: 'eye-off'
            multiline: False
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Confirm Password"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .24}
            helper_text: "*Required"
            helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
            password: True
            icon_left: 'key-variant'
            icon_right: 'eye-off'  
            multiline: False
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Next"
            size_hint_x: .16
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.15}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: "16sp"
            on_release: app.root.current = "signuptwo"
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Have an account? Login!"
            font_size: "13sp"
            size_hint_x: .5
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
            on_release: app.root.current = "login"
        MDLabel:
            id: Name
            text: "Info"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .8}
            font_style: "H6"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, .7
        MDIconButton:
            id: name
            icon: "numeric-1-circle"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .42, "center_y": .75}
            user_font_size: "35sp"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, .7
        MDProgressBar:
            id: progress
            size_hint_x: .11
            size_hint_y: .01
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .495, "center_y":.75}
        MDLabel:
            id: Contact
            text: "Submit"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.03, "center_y": .8}
            font_style: "H6"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
        MDIconButton:
            id: contact
            icon: "numeric-2-circle"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .57, "center_y": .75}
            user_font_size: "35sp"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            

<SignUptwo>:
    name: "signuptwo"

    MDFloatLayout:
        MDCard:
            size_hint: 0.75, 0.9
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        MDLabel:
            text: "Sign-Up"
            bold: True
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
            font_style: "H4"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Age"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .57}
            helper_text: "*Required"
            max_text_length: 2
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDLabel:
            text: "Gender"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .45}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        MDLabel:
            text: "Yes"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.03, "center_y": .50}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        MDLabel:
            text: "No"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.13, "center_y": .50}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        MDLabel:
            text: "Male"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.03, "center_y": .45}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        MDLabel:
            text: "Female"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.11, "center_y": .45}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        
        MDLabel:
            text: "Are you Vaccinated?"
            size_hint_x: 0.4 
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, "center_y": .50}
        MDCheckbox:
            group: "group"
            size_hint_x: 0.07
            size_hint_y: 0.07
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .59, "center_y": .50}
            on_active: app.check(*args)
        MDCheckbox:
            group: "group"
            size_hint_x: 0.07
            size_hint_y: 0.07
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .69, "center_y": .50}
            on_active: app.check1(*args)
        MDCheckbox:
            group: "group1"
            size_hint_x: 0.07
            size_hint_y: 0.07
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .59, "center_y": .45}
            on_active: app.check2(*args)
        MDCheckbox:
            group: "group1"
            size_hint_x: 0.07
            size_hint_y: 0.07
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .69, "center_y": .45}
            on_active: app.check3(*args) 
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Submit"
            size_hint_x: .16
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.23}
            on_release: app.root.current = "riskeval"
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Modify Information!"
            font_size: "13sp"
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            size_hint_x: .5
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, .6
            on_release: app.root.current = "signup"
        MDLabel:
            id: Name
            text: "Info"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .8}
            font_style: "H6"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0,0,1,1
        MDIconButton:
            id: name
            icon: "check-decagram"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .42, "center_y": .75}
            user_font_size: "35sp"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0,0,1,1
        MDProgressBar:
            id: progress
            size_hint_x: .11
            size_hint_y: .01
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .495, "center_y":.75}
            text_color: 0,0,1,1
        MDLabel:
            id: Contact
            text: "Submit"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.03, "center_y": .8}
            font_style: "H6"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
        MDIconButton:
            id: contact
            icon: "numeric-2-circle"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .57, "center_y": .75}
            user_font_size: "35sp"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"







<LoginScreen>:
    name: "login"
    
    MDFloatLayout:

        MDCard:
            size_hint: 0.75, 0.9
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        MDLabel:
            text: "LoginScreen"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
            halign: "center"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            font_size: "35sp"
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "UserName"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
            multiline: False
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDTextField:
            hint_text: "Password"
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .48}
            password: True
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
            multiline: False
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Login"
            size_hint_x: .18
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.5, "center_y":.2}
            on_release: app.root.current = "riskeval"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Login"
            bold: True
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}
            font_style: "H4"
        MDTextButton:
            text: "Don't have an account? Click to create..."
            text_size: 0.2, None
            font_size: "13sp"
            halign: "center"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            size_hint_x: .5
            text_color: 0, 0, 0, 1


<RiskEval>:
    name: "riskeval"

    MDFloatLayout:

        MDTextField:
            id: evaluation
            size_hint_x: .4
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .48}
            password: True
            required: True
            helper_text_mode: "on_error"
            multiline: False
            line_color_normal: app.theme_cls.accent_color
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after long search, dont use size_hint_x and size_hint_y on md buttons. instead delete those lines and set them to none to be safe.